# How to migrate tomcat configurations in Eclipse to Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

i am still new in configure the tomcat server settings. I am asked to move the tomcat configuration from Eclipse IDE to Intellij IDE Ultimate Edition. I have successfully move and import the projects, but the problem is i can't run the tomcat server, how to import the settings like servers.xml, catalina.policy, catalina properties, ssl, etc to Intellij IDE?I can't see where to import the configuration like this in eclipse

[eclipse_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz6IT.png)

This is the tomcat settings configuration:
[intellij_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ubRF.png)

But configuration is very different, how to add like the configuration path and web modules for Intellij configuration? Thank you...

Comment: Configuration path is set when you add or configure the server, there is an option to specify your own CATALINA BASE directory. Context roots and the modules to deploy are specified in the Deployment tab.

Comment: how to set up the catalina base directory? Can you give the example or link for tutorial (With the configuration path settings)? Thanks

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/application-servers-2.html. When you add Tomcat server, there is an option to specify a different base directory: [1](http://i.imgur.com/tY9ApVR.png), [2](http://i.imgur.com/OZG4MGo.png).

Comment: Ok thanks, if  i am not misunderstand i read that the configuration path in eclipse is just actually rewrite the tomcat configuration (server.xml, web.xml and others) from the tomcat that is used. The question is what is JMX port in intellij and what number is needed in my case (i get error message can't ping xxx (Jmx port)? Also where to put the hosts, httpd-ssl, vhosts in tomcat folder?

Comment: In `conf/server.xml` under the base directory, see also https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html#Enabling_JMX_Remote

Comment: i get this error: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]. How to resolve it? I have googling it says that is because jar dependencies corrupt but i am confused how to check it , because the first configuration not me that configure the servers in eclipse.

Edit:
Also i get this error in event log: Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
    Unable to ping server at localhost:8001

Comment: I have another progress when i use the normal tomcat server, i got success page that you have successfully install the servers. But when i configure to modified the settings how to implemented the servers configuration like here in servers folder 

This is the servers folder from eclipse:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Rbt.png

And this is the config in menu.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeYY4.png

How to convert it to intellij tomcat server?

Comment: Update: Now i get this error message:  Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
    java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that Eclipse server configuration cannot be converted fully to  Intellij IDEA, because they work in different ways.

All you need is Servers/pr-config folder, it seems like it is analog for /conf.

Please try the following:

- create separate folder, for example, `<user_folder>/tomcat8_base/conf`
- copy all files from Servers/pr-config to `<user_folder>/tomcat8_base/conf`
- go to Tomcat Run/Debug configuration -> Server tab -> Configure...
- in Application server dialog select your server and

  - change "Tomcat base directory" value to `<user_folder>/tomcat8_base/conf`
  - ensure that Tomcat home directory is still point to full tomcat installation
- apply changes,
- go to Startup/Connection tab
- ensure that you have default Startup script for Run and Debug modes, default startup script is `<tomcat home>\bin\catalina.bat run`
- go to Server tab
- you may specify any port values for HTTP and JMX ports (by default, they have values 8080 and 1099, but any free port should be fine).

IDEA will instruct the server to listen on the selected port(s), the field is editable only to allow user to run complex multiple configurations at the same time with different HTTP / JMX ports

- try to Run Tomcat run-configuration

At this point, if you have any problems, please:

- create new [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue), set Subsystem = JavaEE.Tomcat
- attach there:

  - run console output,
  - idea.log,
  - screenshots of Application servers dialog, Server and Startup/Connection tabs

Comment: Thank you for the answer this solve my problem, i want to ask. I set another computer with same settings, but the artifacts doesn't show/imported automatically in Open Module Settings --> Artifacts. How to rebuild/reimport the artifacts?

Comment: reimport: Artifacts are the project-level notions, with configurations stored inside .idea folder. 

rebuild: I am not sure that you are referring to the same `rebuild` but build actions are available at Main Menu / Build / Build Artifacts...